# why doesn't GitHub see the diff?

Tags: git, github

Below is an image of a GitHub diff. One change is all the code is indented. But there are more significant differences than that that went unnoticed.

[image]

Update:

Looking here:

[image]

Comment: huh? It evidently sees that difference, the whole block is marked as changed.

Comment: You might get a cleaner diff if you tell github to ignore whitespace changes (there is a button somewhere in the UI), but overall it's on you for polluting the diff with insignificant changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why doesn't GitHub see the diff?

It is because the indentations are also changed on those line of codes.

To see the diff while ignoring the whitespace changes, do check the `hide whitespace` checkbox. The option is only available on PR page

[image]

Comment: Can't seem to find that view, smh on GitHub site

Comment: where are you seeing the diff? is it on commit details page, PR, or others?

Comment: commit details page

Comment: I updated the OP of where i am looking

Comment: I found it, seems like only available in Pull Request > commit